# why this deadlock happened ? that is different record

Tags: java, mysql, spring, innodb

show create table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gimDp.jpg)

why this deadlock happened ? that is different record, primary index

I see this two transaction locked different record on primary index

0x00122963
0x00122951
0x00122964

I also see these records in same page ,but it is none business of it

it is trouble me all day.
it is prod problem , i need help

here is detail

```
CREATE TABLE `exchange_task_transfer` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transfer_tx_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划转业务唯一流水号',
  `exchange_tx_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '兑换唯一标识符',
  `biz_req_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '请求划转业务系统的请求流水号，成功处理后更新',
  `from_account_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划出账户ID',
  `from_account_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划出账户类型',
  `to_account_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划入账户ID',
  `to_account_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划入账户类型',
  `transfer_coin` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '划转币种',
  `transfer_amount` decimal(38,18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000000000000000' COMMENT '划转数量',
  `transfer_fee` decimal(38,18) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000000000000000' COMMENT '划转业务收取的手续费数量',
  `remark` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '被拒绝原因',
  `task_index` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '划转业务执行序号',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `transfer_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'init',
  `from_user_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '划出用户id',
  `to_user_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '划入账户用户ID',
  `retry_time` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '补偿次数',
  `source_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'bybit' COMMENT '兑换请求来源，默认是用户主动兑换bybit，碎币兑换small_asset',
  `frozen_status` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '冻结状态',
  `frozen_code` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '冻结流水号',
  `un_frozen_code` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '解冻流水号',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `transfer_tx_id` (`transfer_tx_id`),
  KEY `idx_exchange_task_transfer_exchange_tx_id_IDX` (`exchange_tx_id`,`task_index`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2409 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name: 
Status: 
=====================================
2022-05-25 03:50:14 2ae599f8f700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 19 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 36852555 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 17 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 78334946
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 404800837
Mutex spin waits 54895628542, rounds 65302310425, OS waits 2053849
RW-shared spins 1311851594, rounds 6685693174, OS waits 40412148
RW-excl spins 929838569, rounds 5006233092, OS waits 34882625
Spin rounds per wait: -69.55 mutex, 5.10 RW-shared, 5.38 RW-excl
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-05-23 20:19:50 2ae56c610700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 146745554645, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 9 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 49574537, OS thread handle 0x2ab71af45700, query id 197705807172 10.1.91.91 user_bybit007 updating
UPDATE exchange_task_transfer  SET transfer_tx_id='919122838671294378384223232003',
exchange_tx_id='91912283867129437838422323200',
biz_req_id='1019191129437857549545472',
source_code='bybit',
from_account_id='system',
from_account_type='90',
from_user_id='system',
to_account_id='2283867',
to_account_type='1',
to_user_id='2283867',
transfer_coin='BTC',
transfer_amount=0.136179360000000000,
transfer_fee=0.000000000000000000,
transfer_status='processing',
frozen_status='',
remark='finance transfer processing, requestId:202205237027554273304088101013867',
task_index=3,
retry_time=1,
frozen_code='',
un_frozen_code='',
created_at='2022-05-23 20:19:49',
updated_at='2022-05-23 20:19:50.115'  WHERE id=1190243
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 583 page no 42899 n bits 18 index `PRIMARY` of table `bybitprod`.`exchange_task_transfer` trx id 146745554645 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 18 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91749423; hex= 00122963; asc   )c;;
 1: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe91749427; hex= 00222ab77563; asc  "* uc;;
 2: len=7; bufptr=0x2abe9174942d; hex= 8b00044007011d; asc    @   ;;
 3: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe91749434; hex= 393139313232383338363731323934333738333834323233323332303033; asc 919122838671294378384223232003;;
 4: len=29; bufptr=0x2abe91749452; hex= 3931393132323833383637313239343337383338343232333233323030; asc 91912283867129437838422323200;;
 5: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe9174946f; hex= ; asc ;;
 6: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe9174946f; hex= 73797374656d; asc system;;
 7: len=2; bufptr=0x2abe91749475; hex= 3930; asc 90;;
 8: len=7; bufptr=0x2abe91749477; hex= 32323833383637; asc 2283867;;
 9: len=1; bufptr=0x2abe9174947e; hex= 31; asc 1;;
 10: len=3; bufptr=0x2abe9174947f; hex= 425443; asc BTC;;
 11: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe91749482; hex= 800000000000000000081deea000000000; asc                  ;;
 12: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe91749493; hex= 8000000000000000000000000000000000; asc                  ;;
 13: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe917494a4; hex= e8b4a2e58aa1e58892e8bdacefbc8ce58591e585a5e5b881e7a78de79a84; asc                               ; (total 51 bytes);
 14: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe917494d7; hex= 80000003; asc     ;;
 15: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe917494db; hex= 628bec65; asc b  e;;
 16: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe917494df; hex= 628bec65; asc b  e;;
 17: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe917494e3; hex= 696e6974; asc init;;
 18: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe917494e7; hex= 73797374656d; asc system;;
 19: len=7; bufptr=0x2abe917494ed; hex= 32323833383637; asc 2283867;;
 20: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe917494f4; hex= 80000000; asc     ;;
 21: len=5; bufptr=0x2abe917494f8; hex= 6279626974; asc bybit;;
 22: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe917494fd; hex= ; asc ;;
 23: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe917494fd; hex= ; asc ;;
 24: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe917494fd; hex= ; asc ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 146745552073, ACTIVE 1 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 25427 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1215668 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 49574547, OS thread handle 0x2ae5d36da700, query id 197705802508 10.1.207.206 user_bybit007 Searching rows for update
update exchange_task_transfer set frozen_status = 'lock', remark='资产冻结成功' where frozen_code = '20720615640769129437730200764416XDC_LOCK'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 583 page no 42899 n bits 2 index `PRIMARY` of table `bybitprod`.`exchange_task_transfer` trx id 146745552073 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe9174808d; hex= 00122951; asc   )Q;;
 1: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe91748091; hex= 00222ab72957; asc  "* )W;;
 2: len=7; bufptr=0x2abe91748097; hex= 2000a0c01c306d; asc      0m;;
 3: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe9174809e; hex= 323037323036313536343037363931323934333737333032303037363434; asc 207206156407691294377302007644; (total 34 bytes);
 4: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe917480c0; hex= 323037323036313536343037363931323934333737333032303037363434; asc 207206156407691294377302007644; (total 32 bytes);
 5: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe917480e0; hex= ; asc ;;
 6: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe917480e0; hex= 3135363430373730; asc 15640770;;
 7: len=1; bufptr=0x2abe917480e8; hex= 32; asc 2;;
 8: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe917480e9; hex= 3230393633363638; asc 20963668;;
 9: len=1; bufptr=0x2abe917480f1; hex= 32; asc 2;;
 10: len=3; bufptr=0x2abe917480f2; hex= 4c5443; asc LTC;;
 11: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe917480f5; hex= 80000000000000000000d9e31000000000; asc                  ;;
 12: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe91748106; hex= 8000000000000000000000000000000000; asc                  ;;
 13: len=18; bufptr=0x2abe91748117; hex= e8b584e4baa7e586bbe7bb93e68890e58a9f; asc                   ;;
 14: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91748129; hex= 80000001; asc     ;;
 15: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe9174812d; hex= 628bec55; asc b  U;;
 16: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91748131; hex= 628bec5d; asc b  ];;
 17: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91748135; hex= 696e6974; asc init;;
 18: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe91748139; hex= 3135363430373639; asc 15640769;;
 19: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe91748141; hex= 3230393633363637; asc 20963667;;
 20: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91748149; hex= 80000000; asc     ;;
 21: len=11; bufptr=0x2abe9174814d; hex= 736d616c6c5f6173736574; asc small_asset;;
 22: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91748158; hex= 6c6f636b; asc lock;;
 23: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe9174815c; hex= 323037323036313536343037363931323934333737333032303037363434; asc 207206156407691294377302007644; (total 40 bytes);
 24: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe91748184; hex= 323037323036313536343037363931323934333737333032303037363434; asc 207206156407691294377302007644; (total 47 bytes);

[bitmap0 of 16 bytes in hex: fc ff 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 583 page no 42899 n bits 22 index `PRIMARY` of table `bybitprod`.`exchange_task_transfer` trx id 146745552073 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 22 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 25; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe9174986e; hex= 00122964; asc   )d;;
 1: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe91749872; hex= 00222ab776d5; asc  "* v ;;
 2: len=7; bufptr=0x2abe91749878; hex= 0b004dc03104b6; asc   M 1  ;;
 3: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe9174987f; hex= 393139313232383338363731323934333738333834323233323332303032; asc 919122838671294378384223232002;;
 4: len=29; bufptr=0x2abe9174989d; hex= 3931393132323833383637313239343337383338343232333233323030; asc 91912283867129437838422323200;;
 5: len=25; bufptr=0x2abe917498ba; hex= 31303139313931313239343337383537343236393732363732; asc 1019191129437857426972672;;
 6: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe917498d3; hex= 3230393633363638; asc 20963668;;
 7: len=1; bufptr=0x2abe917498db; hex= 32; asc 2;;
 8: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe917498dc; hex= 73797374656d; asc system;;
 9: len=2; bufptr=0x2abe917498e2; hex= 3930; asc 90;;
 10: len=3; bufptr=0x2abe917498e4; hex= 425443; asc BTC;;
 11: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe917498e7; hex= 8000000000000000000820031600000000; asc                  ;;
 12: len=17; bufptr=0x2abe917498f8; hex= 8000000000000000000002147600000000; asc             v    ;;
 13: len=30; bufptr=0x2abe91749909; hex= 66696e616e6365207472616e736665722070726f63657373696e672c2072; asc finance transfer processing, r; (total 72 bytes);
 14: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91749951; hex= 80000002; asc     ;;
 15: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91749955; hex= 628bec65; asc b  e;;
 16: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91749959; hex= 628bec66; asc b  f;;
 17: len=10; bufptr=0x2abe9174995d; hex= 70726f63657373696e67; asc processing;;
 18: len=8; bufptr=0x2abe91749967; hex= 3230393633363637; asc 20963667;;
 19: len=6; bufptr=0x2abe9174996f; hex= 73797374656d; asc system;;
 20: len=4; bufptr=0x2abe91749975; hex= 80000001; asc     ;;
 21: len=5; bufptr=0x2abe91749979; hex= 6279626974; asc bybit;;
 22: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe9174997e; hex= ; asc ;;
 23: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe9174997e; hex= ; asc ;;
 24: len=0; bufptr=0x2abe9174997e; hex= ; asc ;;
```

Comment: One is using `id`, one is using `frozen_code`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: i add a picture

Comment: table structure in front of detail

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: @RickJames 1239884 rows

Answer (score 0):

`frozen_code` is not indexed, so `UPDATE ... WHERE frozen_code = '...';` will scan the entire table, bumping into the lock that the other transaction has (or will have).

Suggest adding `INDEX(frozen_code)`.

**More**

I think, but am not sure, that this is happening (without the index):

Xaction 2 (frozen_code) starts
Xaction 2 locks rows as it scans for the row(s) to Update
Xaction 1 starts and tries to lock the one row it needs
Deadlock occurs and one of the transactions is rolled back.
Xaction ROLLBACK (for the loser)
Xaction finish and COMMIT (for the winner)

With the index, the two transactions might not collide over any rows, and all works smoothly.

Comment: But why transaction2 hold a record lock , and record row is 0x00122951

Comment: I don't understand, transaction1 didn't hold a lock, why deadlock

Comment: The table scan tries to lock every row.  The Index fixes that.

Comment: yes, the transaction2 lock every row , but it could finish , why dead, the transaction 1 didn't hold the lock that transaction2 need

Comment: @chunlaiqingke - In some cases (I think this is one of them), InnoDB locks more rows than necessary.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: @chunlaiqingke - I wrote more.